# Python regular expression to get all image src from a string'

Tags: python, regex

how to use python re to get all image src
for example

```
a = "images src <img src=\"http://aa/6.png\" /> <img src=\"http://aa/7.png\" /> "
```

i want to get

```
data = {
'content': 'images src',
'src': ['http://aa/6.png', 'http://aa/7.png']
}
```

how to do it

Comment: *how to do it* - by using a html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it with `regex`:

```
import re

data = {'content': 'images src',
        'src': re.findall('src="([^"]+)"', a)
```

Output:

```
{'content': 'images src', 'src': ['http://aa/6.png', 'http://aa/7.png']}
```

Comment: It's not critical since OP asked how to `get all image src` not how to get `content`.

Answer (score 3):

Using something which is beautiful, [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = "images src <img src=\"http://aa/6.png\" /> <img src=\"http://aa/7.png\" /> "
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
page_images = [image["src"] for image in soup.findAll("img")]
print(page_images)
```

Hence using a `dict` to store the results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup        
data = {}
a = "images src <img src=\"http://aa/6.png\" /> <img src=\"http://aa/7.png\" /> "
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
page_images = [image["src"] for image in soup.findAll("img")]

content = a.split("<")[0]
data['content'] = content
data['src'] = page_images

print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'content': 'images src ', 'src': ['http://aa/6.png', 'http://aa/7.png']}
```

But if regex is preferred:

```
import re

data = {}
a = "images src <img src=\"http://aa/6.png\" /> <img src=\"http://aa/7.png\" /> "
content = a.split("<")[0]

data['content'] = content
if re.search('src="([^"]+)"',a):
  data['src'] = re.findall ('src="(.*?)"', a, re.DOTALL)

print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'content': 'images src ', 'src': ['http://aa/6.png', 'http://aa/7.png']}
```

Comment: Maybe a  more safe regex would be like so `.*<img +src *= *" *([a-zA-Z0-9:\/.]+) *" +\/>.*`

Comment: @MattB. glad to see you again! :)